# Как создать несколько объектов с одинаковым именем, одного класса отличающихся по атрибуту?

Tags: python, python-2.x

```
class Store(object):
    def __init__(self, price=0):
        self.price = price


bananas = Store(price=9)
bananas = Store(price=12)
print (bananas.price)
```

Comment: Используйте список для хранения таких объектов `bananas = []; bananas.append(Store(9))`

Comment: По другому никак?

Comment: что значит 'одинаковых' объектов?

Comment: @trthhrtz обьектов одного класса

Comment: @AlexZaharchuk объекты одного класса не одинаковы

Comment: Извиняюсь, если не корректно выразился, я имел ввиду, например: что бы магазин имел два одинаковых продукта, но различных по ценне.

Comment: Есть в python zen строчка такая `"Пространства имён — отличная штука! Будем делать их больше!"`. Только без фанатизма.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
class Store(object):

    _singleton = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls._singleton is None:
            cls._singleton = super(Store, cls).__new__(cls)
        return cls._singleton

    def __init__(self, price=0):
        self.price = getattr(self, 'price', [])
        self.price.append(price)


bananas = Store(price=9)
bananas = Store(price=12)
print(bananas.price)
```

UPD: Судя по тому пояснению, которое вы дали в комменте вам всё-таки стоит использовать что-то вроде:

```
store1 = Store()
bananas1 = Banana(9)
bananas2 = Banana(12)
store1.add_item(bananas1)
store1.add_item(bananas2)
```

Comment: А можете немного пояснить? Выдает ошибку `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'price'`

Comment: @iamsuperoleg, у меня там была опечатка, теперь я поправил. Но вообще, будет лучше, если вы опишите общую задачу, которую решаете. Потому что такое впечатление, что у вас "проблема молотка" https://tproger.ru/explain/xyproblem/

Comment: "проблемы молотка" нет :) Это одно из условий задания по созданию магазина, которое я решаю. https://gist.github.com/iamsuperoleg/fb496495754e67e5f4f15f513d72befe

Comment: понял вас, спасибо!

Answer (score -1):

```
class Store(object):
    def __init__(self, name, price=0):
        self.name = name
        self.price = price

class StoresList(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.stores = dict()

    def add(self, store):
        self.stores[store.name] = store

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return self.stores[item]

    def get_by_price(self, price):
        for item in self.stores:
            if self.stores[item] == price:
                return self.stores[item]


my_stores = StoresList()
my_stores.add(Store('Name1', 10))
my_stores.add(Store('Name2', 100))

print(my_stores.Name1.price)
print(my_stores.Name2.price)

print(my_stores.get_by_price(100))
```